# How to solve npm run build 137 error? Already have set 10gb

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, npm, angular-cli

I am running npm run build to create a docker. It has --prod option. If ran without --prod it builds fine. If built with --prod it goes into 137 ENDLIFECYCLE error.

Killed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137

Unfortunately i can't just remove the prod option, cos thats what works on dev machine and I am just supposed to be doing devops.

I saw many places that its because of memory low, so i set the variable
NODE_OPTIONS --max-old-space-size

It is at 10GB currently and it is not helping. And i can build same docker in my machine with 8GB.

This build is happening inside jenkins and i did a free -m inside docker just to see, the server has 64GB memory.

So what could be the issue?

Comment: adding --verbose helped us fix in short term. It *seems* like some process was killing it becuase it sees no output from npm run build. command used is npm run build -- --prod --verbose

Comment: Were you able to figure out the issue @manu ?

Answer (score 5):

Did you try increasing memory available for docker via Docker > Preferences... > Advanced > Ram. It defaults to only 2 GB (on mac).

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any framework?
you can check this two option 'optimization','aot' in angular.json
(If you use angular)

turn it to false maybe can resolve your problem temporarily
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru3vh.png)

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue , i updated angular to version 12 and all the dependencies to 12 it helped